# Teamcity "git repository" error

Tags: github, teamcity

After migrating a project from "subversion" to "githhub" **successfully**,
I am trying to build it by hitting "run" in "teamcity" but getting the following 
error:
[image]

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expecting to be inside an actual Git repository so it can generate the GitVersion correctly.

You'll need to **install git on your build agents** and ensure that code is checked out on the agent. Further information as to why this needs to be done can be found in the [TeamCity Checkout Mode Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/VCS+Checkout+Mode)

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: i dont find "checkout options" is it in the left pane?

Comment: If you look in the Build Configuration Settings => Version Control Settings you should find it here